# Gmail SMTP connect failures using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am aware that there are a number of open questions regarding this, I have spent the better part of several hours reading through them and researching my issue. Additionally, I have taken the steps outlined in the extremely thorough troubleshooting guide provided by PHPMailer. In the end however, I remain stumped. I am getting this error regardless of the steps I take to resolve:

```
2018-01-16 19:16:15 Connection: opening to 173.194.203.108:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2018-01-16 19:18:22 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to 173.194.203.108:587 (Connection timed out) [/home6/rightme1/public_html/netWorks/emailtests/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 326]
2018-01-16 19:18:22 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have exhausted several avenues...
My smtp.gmail.com ping was successful.
I tested using telnet.
I confirmed the ports were open on server and firewall.
I tried three different ways of specifying the host.

```
$mail->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Host ='tls://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
```

Here is the code that connects to the server...

```
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'login@email.com';                  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pW0rd';                            // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable SSL/TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted using port 465
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a non-google smtp account anywhere? If you do, does your code succeed or fail with that one?

Comment: I have a yahoo account. I can try it with that.

Comment: I got a gateway timeout with yahoo host.

Comment: Do you know anyone with a corporate e-mail smtp account who would let you test. Something hosted on their own comany server instead of google, yahoo, microsoft giant public e-mail services?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This is telling you that the network your server is on is blocking outbound SMTP traffic. If you have shell access (i.e. not shared hosting), you can use the `telnet` and `openssl` tests from the guide to confirm that. Your hosting provider probably has some alternative solution that they will have documented somewhere. GoDaddy is well known for doing this.

Comment: I am using PuTTY ... telnet test are failing. My host is convinced the ports are open.

Comment: Would the host be the same relay as is listed for godaddy?

Answer (score 0):

After further research, the host noted that it is not possible to use PHPMailer on their servers.